# Django Inline Formsets - clean() method not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

So I have a django inline formset created by django.forms.inlineformset_factory, which contains a parent: ParentCount, and child: ChildCount.

Inside the ChildCount form I have rewritten the clean method as such:

```
class ChildCountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ChildCount
        exclude = ["name"]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ChildCountForm, self).clean()

        att1 = cleaned_data.get("att1")
        att2 = cleaned_data.get("att2")

        if att1 == "I3i" and att2 is None:
            msg = "Require att2 information for I3i attribute"
            self._errors['att2'] = self.error_class([msg])

        """Returns the cleaned data"""
        return cleaned_data
```

I thought this would get called for each ChildForm inside the formset, as the inlineformset_factory is defined using a custom form class, which uses the logic:

```
class CustomInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    """used to pass in the constructor of inlineformset_factory"""
    def clean(self):
        """forces each clean() method on the ChildCounts to be called"""
        super(BaseInlineFormSet, self).clean()
        for form in self.forms:
            form.clean()

ChildFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ParentCount, ChildCount,
                                     form=ParentCountForm,
                                     extra=1,
                                     max_num=30,
                                     formset=CustomInlineFormset)
```

However, at this point in the form, the clean method() of each form is not derived from ChildCountForm, it's derived from BaseModelForm. If I instantiate an empty ChildCountForm at that line in the pdb, it says it derives the clean method from ChildCountForm, but the 'form' object in self.forms doesn't. Why is this?

How can I get my custom clean() method to run for each ChildForm?

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood what the `inlineformset_factory` is doing. It creates the formset for the child forms, so you if you want to specify a custom form you should pass in ChildCountForm.

Note also that calling the clean method of each form is the default behaviour, so there is no need to override the formset to do that.

Comment: Passing in ChildCountForm causes no forms to be rendered?